# Мигает Bloom при движении камеры

Tags: unity3d

У меня имеется спрайт, на котором лежит скрипт SpriteGlow (нашел на [гитхабе](https://github.com/Elringus/SpriteGlow)). Он добавляет внешнее свечение спрайту. Чтобы получить свечение использую Bloom в Post Processing Stack.
Когда камера приходит в движение, bloom начинает мигать, что смотрится некрасиво.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить ситуацию.
Настройки PP: [image: настройки]

Comment: У меня имеется код непонятного происхождения, я вам его не дам, также у меня есть настроенный стэк PP, его я вам тоже не дам, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А пример проблемы кроме словесного описания вы не можете предоставить?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eldNPB45Qs&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение которое удовлетворяет меня. Что бы избавиться от мерцание нужно в параметрах URP Asset в категории "Quality" указать Render Scale = 2. После чего мерцание совсем не заметна.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]